# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - setting new version of gcc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

I have built gcc 4.8.2 based on the following community wiki answer: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271388/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-in-ubuntu-12-04-from-the-terminal) When I check current gcc version in a terminal I get an info: 4.6.3 How to set the new gcc 4.8.2 as default ?

**Solution:** Remove **--prefix=/app/gcc/4.8.0** from step 3 (community wiki answer). Besides libraries which are mentioned in step 2 I had to install also g++ and multilib.

Comment: Where did you configure the install to go? What did you specify for `--prefix=/x/y/z` in the configure command line?  For whatever name you specified, you need to put `/x/y/z/bin` on your PATH ahead of the system directories.  If you installed into `/usr`, you will need to change the existing `/usr/bin/gcc` so that it becomes a link to or copy of your new `gcc` (apparently, it still is a link to or copy of the older version).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building from source, and possibly losing all valuable patches the distro maintainers add, you should use the [Ubuntu toolchain PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ppa) which is maintained by the actual gcc maintainer.

Once you have the newer version, and possibly other intermediate versions, you can then chose between several binaries:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/gcc-4* /usr/bin/gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Oct 11 21:47 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 255168 Jan 30  2013 /usr/bin/gcc-4.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 275952 Jul  2  2012 /usr/bin/gcc-4.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 357344 Jun 19  2013 /usr/bin/gcc-4.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 578840 Sep 23 15:24 /usr/bin/gcc-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 775888 Nov 15 09:35 /usr/bin/gcc-4.8
$
```

You can then pick the desired version by setting `CC` as a Makefile variable and various other means.  You could also use `dpkg-alternative` to override the default (which in my Ubuntu 13.10 system just move from 4.5 to 4.8 with the most recent upgrade from 13.04).

Answer (score 0):

Try to download source code from here ======>  http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/

```
tar xzf gcc-4.8.2.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.8.2


./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-4.8.2/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.8.2 
make
make install
```